# Is the hard problem of consciousness based on a faulty premise?

Tags: consciousness

The hard problem of consciousness is the problem of explaining why any physical state is conscious rather than nonconscious. It is the problem of explaining why there is “something it is like” for a subject in conscious experience, why conscious mental states “light up” and directly appear to the subject.

But why does this require an explanation? What evidence is there to suggest that there is a **need** for explanation in the first place? What if certain physical processes correspond to conscious processes…and that’s that?

When doing physics, there are certain questions that many physicists consider inappropriate questions. These questions include “why does the universe exist?” or “What is the purpose of this universe?” or “why are the laws of physics set in a way where we have spherical planets that look like balls rather than planets that look like cubes?”

You’d be hard pressed to find a physicist that would give you a satisfactory answer to any of those questions. Most would say there is no further reason or no further question to be answered. They would say that some things just happen without further cause or reason. Why can’t the same apply to consciousness?

What if there simply is no further explanation to why certain physical processes correspond to conscious processes? What could an explanation to this even look like?

Comment: `What if certain physical processes correspond to conscious processes…and that’s that?` - even most physicalists agree that there's something there we'd like to understand about how physical interactions produce the things we think, feel, experience. It's not obvious. It's hard.

Comment: @TKoL What would a how look like and why does that indicate there’s something more to understand?

Comment: We know we don't understand consciousness - we don't know how to simulate it (we are debatably close, in regards to ai), nor do we know even a ballpark for how to tell if a system is conscious. How could someone say they understand consciousness if they literally don't even know what to look for to decide if a physical thing is for sure conscious or not?

Comment: @TKoL But we can differentiate though. We know that rocks, chairs, and many other kinds of objects aren’t conscious. We also know that we aren’t conscious during sleep (most of the time). Can we **prove** this? Maybe not. But we can’t prove the world is real either and a whole host of other things so consciousness isn’t special.

Comment: "“why are the laws of physics set in a way where we have spherical planets that look like balls rather than planets that look like cubes?” most physicists would probably tell you that planets being spherical is a consequence of the laws rather than the laws being set to make planets spherical.  If you like Occam's razor, that is a reasonable answer as well, the laws that would result in cuboid planets would have to be very complicated.  "“What is the purpose of this universe?”" not a scientific question, so why ask a scientist? "“why does the universe exist?”" what do you mean by "why"?